# Prevent users from accessing .jsp except by forwarding

Tags: java, servlets

I have a MVC website with java technologies.  I have a number of .jsp which when routed to via proper servlets work fine, but when accessed directly appear not to work.  I want to prevent my users from direct addressing the .jsps.

That is they can use `www.url.com/Website/MyServlet`, which would then forward them to `www.url.com/Website/MyServlet.jsp`, but I want to prevent them from direct addressing to`www.url.com/Website/MyServlet.jsp` since the `HttpServletRequest` will be missing attributes and will not display correctly.  Surely this must be common practice? How do I accomplice this, can I write a mapping which redirects all *.jsp to not founds unless it is a forward?

I bet I could write a filter that picks up all non FORWARD directives (INCLUDE REQUEST etc) mapped to *.jsp and send 404 for them but Im thinking there must be a eaisier way? Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you should be working out exactly *why* it doesn't work when accessed directly...

Comment: Disagree with @JonSkeet. Very common to use controllers to forward to JSPs with certain attributes set, in which case it is undesirable to allow direct access to the JSP.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I know exactly that. It is MVC and an upstream servlet prepares the output data which is attached to the request and forwarded to the view jsp to output it.  If you access the view directly there is no data attached to the request and the view has nothing meaningful to display. I of course can catch this and display a message but routing to the proper servlet would work better.

Comment: @Jon: those kind of JSPs function as a "view" which require a preprocessing "controller" which prepares all the data which needs to be presented in HTML by JSP. Directly accessing the JSPs would skip the preprocessing job altogether. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: Okay, if it's *understood* why it doesn't work, that's fine. But "appear not to work" makes it sounds like you don't understand it. I have a phobia of working round a problem before understanding it.

Comment: @BalusC: That's all fine - it just wasn't clear from the question that the cause was understood.

Comment: I should have been more clear, I suppose. I intended "appears not to work to the user" not "appears not to work to me"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put them in `/WEB-INF` folder and change the forward paths accordingly.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/MyServlet.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Files in `/WEB-INF` (and `/META-INF`) folder are not publicly accessible.

Comment: PS:  This sort of view mapping is built into pretty much any modern framework which supports JSP (ie. spring, structs, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

By default Web Containers does not allow resources under `WEB-INF` folder to be accessed directly. You can put jsp's inside `WEB-INF` folder.

You can then write a filter to `include/forward` to the jsp

Answer (score 0):

Put code in the JSP that detects whether the necessary conditions are met and takes appropriate action, such as forwarding to the controller servlet or directing users to the appropriate place, and does not attempt to render the "correct" JSP if necessary conditions are not met.

Comment: BalusC's answer might be more technically correct. Either way should work; it depends on whether you want to have to update each `request.getRequestDispatcher()...` for any JSP filename changes, or update each JSP for any servlet URL changes. Leaving updates and forwarding in Java code (as in BalusC's answer) is cleaner, IMO, but it's possible there could be a situation in which you would want to update and take action in the JSP instead.